# Prove that two random variates must be negatively correlated

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, correlation, moment-generating-functions

## Problem statement

Given the probability density
$$ p(s,t|a,b,c) = \cases{Z(a,b,c)^{-1} \exp(-as-bt-cst) &if $s \geq 1$ and $t \geq 1$ \\ 0 &otherwise} \label{1} \tag{1}$$
where
$$ \begin{align} 
Z(a,b,c) &\equiv \int \int \exp(-as-bt-cst) \ ds \ dt = \frac{1}{c} \exp\Big(\frac{ab}{c}\Big) \Gamma\Big(0,\frac{(a+c)(b+c)}{c}\Big) \\
\Gamma(0,x) &= \int_x^\infty \exp(-t) \frac{dt}{t}
\end{align} $$
and $(a,b,c)$ are "admissible" such that $Z(a,b,c)$ exists, i.e.,
$$ c > 0, \quad a + c > 0, \quad b + c > 0.$$

Prove (or disprove) that for any such admissible $(a,b,c)$:
$$ \langle st \rangle \leq \langle s \rangle \langle t \rangle. \label{2} \tag{2}$$
In other words, the random variates $(s,t)$ must be negatively correlated.

## Comments

### Lower bound on $\langle st \rangle$

For all $(s,t)$ in the support of \eqref{1} we have $1 \leq (s,t) \leq st$. So $1 \leq \max(\langle s \rangle, \langle t \rangle) \leq \langle st \rangle$.

### The case $c=0$

If $c=0$ the random variates $(s,t)$ are independent and thus uncorrelated, such that \eqref{2} reduces to $\langle st \rangle = \langle s \rangle \langle t \rangle.$

### Background

Given the constraints:
$$ 1 \leq (s,t) < L, \quad \langle s \rangle = S, \quad \langle t \rangle = T, \quad \langle st \rangle = U $$
the density \eqref{1} is the [maximum entropy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_maximum_entropy) with respect to Lebesgue measure for $L \rightarrow \infty$ where $(a,b,c)$ are admissible Lagrange multipliers which solve the simultaneous equations:
$$ -\nabla_{a,b,c} \log Z \equiv (\langle s \rangle, \langle t \rangle, \langle st \rangle) = (S,T,U). \label{3} \tag{3}$$
Thus by construction \eqref{1} is in the [exponential family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family).

I implemented a numerical solver that finds admissible $(a,b,c)$ for given $(S,T,U)$ but it fails badly when $U$ is moderately larger than $ST$: it drives $c \rightarrow 0$ but cannot accurately satisfy \eqref{3}. Further numerical investigation led me to believe (95% sure) that \eqref{3} can only be solved when $U \leq ST$, but after much effort I could not prove this.

I tried several approaches to prove \eqref{2} (e.g. directly attacking \eqref{2}; bounding $\langle st \rangle$ with the moment generating function of \eqref{1}) but the only noteworthy result I could get is the following:

> For $c \approx 0$, the solution to \eqref{3} is roughly:
> $$ a = \frac{1}{S-1}, \quad b = \frac{1}{T-1}, \quad c = -\frac{U - ST}{S^2(T-1)^2 + T^2(S-1)^2 + (S-1)^2 (T-1)^2}. $$
> This can be obtained by a first-order expansion of \eqref{3} at $c = 0$ and solving for $(a,b,c)$.
> Since $c > 0$, we must have that $U < ST$, such that \eqref{2} holds.

I'm unsure what the significance of this result in relation to proving \eqref{2} might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

Your conjecture is true. Long answer is follows.

### Long answer

I'll start by giving two simple inequalities, one is a special case of an important inequality, one is an inequality I crafted just for my work.

#### Preliminaries

**Theorem 1** (Special case of FKG inequality)
Let $X$ be real random variable, $f$ and $g$ be two real increasing functions such that $f(X),g(X) \in L^2$. Then,
$$ \mathbb{E}( f(X)g(X)) \ge \mathbb{E}(f(X))\mathbb{E}(g(X)) $$
**Demonstration 2** 
We extend our probability space to have another random variable $X_1$ which independent of and identically distributed to $X$.
By the monotonicity of $f,g$, we have:
$$ \mathbb{E}\left[  (f(X)-f(X_1))(g(X)-g(X_1) \right] \ge 0 $$

Our desired inequality is just the our expression after expanding.
Done.

**Theorem 3** ( Logdensity and the morphing of distribution functions)
Let $X$ and $Y$ be two real random variables, $h$ and $g$ are their respective *pseudo densities* (definitions below).
Suppose that :
$$ \frac{h(t)}{h(s)} \ge \frac{g(t)}{g(s)} \forall t\ge s$$

Let $f$ be any increasing function such that $\mathbb{E}( f(X))$ and $\mathbb{E}( f(Y))$  are well defined, then
$$ \mathbb{E}(f(X)) \ge \mathbb{E}(f(Y))$$

*Remark 4* the above inequality is taked in the sense that $\frac{a}{b} \ge \frac{c}{d} \leftrightarrow ad-bc \ge 0$ for all $b,d \ge 0$ ) .
*Remark 5* all the conditions about $L^2$ about the well-definedness are just there to make all the statements valid, i.e, they are just technical, just forget it. The essence is the inequalities
*Remark 6*: (Definition of pseudo density) A measurable function $f$ is called a pseudo density if $f$ is nonnegative and $0< \int f < +\infty$. Clearly, by then $\tilde{f}:= \dfrac{f}{|f|_1}$ is a density function.
**Demonstration 6**

Under our assumption on the monotonicity and  the inequality for logdensity, we have:

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \left[ f(s)- f(t)\right] [ h(s)g(t)-h(t)g(s) ]dsdt \ge 0$$
Thus,
$$ \Vert g \Vert_1 \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(s)h(s)ds \ge \Vert h \Vert_1 \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(s)g(s)ds  $$
Done.

*Remark 7* FKG's inequality has some interesting generalizations, but they are not within our scope.
*Remark 8* The intuition behind those inequalities is that if we assign something big with other big things, something small with other small things, we should have some kind of increment.
*Remark 9* If $\log h, \log g$ is well defined and have derivatives, the above inequality condition case be rephrased as  $ \dfrac{\partial \log h }{\partial t} \ge \dfrac{\partial \log g }{\partial t}$

*Back to our main question*

#### Main question

Let $h_s := p( s , \cdot |a,b,c)$
If $(a,b,c)$ is an admissble choice, we have:
$$ \dfrac{ \partial^2 \log h_s(t)}{\partial s \partial t} = -c < 0 $$
Thus for all $s_1< s_2$, we have:
$$ \dfrac{\partial \log h_{s_1} }{\partial t} \ge \dfrac{\partial \log h_{s_2} }{\partial t}$$

Besides, we see that $h_s$ is the peusdo density of the conditional law of $T$, given $\{S=s\}$ 
.
As $f(x):=x$ is an increasing function, we hence imply that :
$$ g(s):= \mathbb{E}\left( T| S=s \right) \text{ is a decreasing function}$$

So, we see:
$$\langle ST \rangle = \mathbb{E}(ST) = \mathbb{E}\left( S \mathbb{E}(T|S) \right)= \mathbb{E}\left( f(S)g(S) \right) \underbrace{\le}_{FKG's} \mathbb{E}(S) \mathbb{E}(g(S)) = \langle S \rangle \langle T \rangle $$
(Note that $f$ is increasing, while $g$ is decreasing)
So the answer is **Affirmative**.

#### Comments

- So you see the sign of $\dfrac{ \partial^2 \log p}{\partial s \partial t}$ implies the sign of correlation.
- The theorem 3 gives some sense of the behaviour of $\mathcal{L}(T|S=s)$ when $s$ varies.

Comment: After study, I've come to the conclusion that this answer is absolutely incredible. Thank you very much for the work you have put into this and for the clear explanation!

Comment: I interpret your second inequality (Theorem 3) roughly as: "If one density ($h$) decays slower as another one ($g$), then the expectation of an increasing function $f$ under $h$ is larger than under $g$."

Comment: Yeah, you're correct. Nice visual interpretation, though I think if I were you, I'd be more careful when our density also decays in x-negative direction because, in that situation, the term "decay" does not really sum up our condition.

Comment: Thank you for your praise.